# Retrieve data from URL but receive error: iterator should return strings, not bytes

Tags: python, python-3.x, iterator

I am trying to get this python script on this github to work.

https://gist.github.com/lebedov/f09030b865c4cb142af1

The script retrieves stock quotes from Google.

When I run the function `stock = get_google_finance_intraday("AAPL")`, I get the error `_csv.Error: iterator should return strings, not bytes (did you open the file in text mode?)`

I traced to the line of code that caused the error.

It is line 39.

```
reader = csv.reader(page.content.splitlines())
```

I am using python v3.6. I suspect the code runs on python v2 but not v3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

python 3 requires you to decode byte arrays (data from files) into actual strings

```
data = data.decode('utf8')
```

you'll want to do this on the lines pulled before passing them to the csv parser.

Answer (score 0):

now it seems intraday is not working only returning daily price
try this:
https://www.google.com/finance/getprices?i=60&p=10d&f=d,o,h,l,c,v&df=cpct&q=IBM

Answer (score 0):

But the following DOES work for intraday prices: 
https://finance.google.com/finance/getprices?q=IBM&p=1d&i=60&f=d,o,h,l,c,v
Note the change in URL.